# EF Core allow to map private fields to models. But how I could select this private field without retrieving whole model

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

EF Core allows mapping private fields to models. But how I could select this private field without retrieving the whole model? Let's say if I have a large model for a Car and have private property - `Fuel consumption` how could I get the only id with fuel consumption data?

Comment: Can't you use linq? `.Select(x => new Car { Id = x.Id, FuelConsumption = x.FuelConsumption });`

Comment: `FuelConsumption` is a private member so you can't access it - that's basically the question's dilemma

Comment: What is the defination for `Car` and `Fuel`?